how to incrementally load fact table that sources from more than one table
I need help determining how to load a fact table incrementally.  The fact table sources from several tables.  All source tables have a watermark (update timestamp) column.  The source tables vary in size, but some are large.  Hence, I need to load my fact table incrementally.  If it matters, the source tables are joined before the load of the fact table.  Given all this, how can I load my fact table incrementally?
If the fact table only sourced from one table (or, if the source tables were merely unioned), my solution would be to use a "control" table that saves the previous "high watermark" from the source table(s) (which is used to determine which rows to fetch from the source table(s) during the next load of the fact table).  (Specifically, the "control" table has a row with information about the source table(s), its previous "high watermark", and the fact table.)  However, since more than one source table is involved, this solution won't work.  At least, I don't think it will work, since it doesn't account for the relationships (i.e., the join) between the source tables (e.g., source table A might not have updates but source table B may have updates).

Can you provide a concrete example of fact data spread over multiple source tables? I would have thought there would always be an identifiable main table for any fact, even if ancillary information was held in other tables
